# Pandas: Average values in DataFrame column if string in adjacent column contains substring from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I've been stuck on this for a while! I've got these two pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

color_scores = pd.DataFrame({'score': [12.4, 9.8, 7.4, 2.6, 14.8],
                   'colors': ['blue, red, green', 'blue, purple, orange',
                   'blue, pink, yellow', 'purple, pink, orange',
                   'yellow, pink, green']})

color_avgs = pd.DataFrame({'colors': [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'green',
    'purple',
    'orange',
    'pink',
    'yellow',
    ]})
```

What I'm trying to do is create a second column in `color_avgs` which would be the average of the values in `color_scores['score']` if the string in `color_scores['colors]` contains the substring/color from `color_avgs['colors']`.

I know how I can do this manually for each color (below). However, I don't know how to loop over all the colors listed in `color_avgs['colors']`, and add the result to a new column (`color_avgs['average']`).

```
color_scores.loc[color_scores['colors'].str.contains('blue'), 'score'].mean()
9.866666666666667
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
from collections import Counter

c1, c2 = Counter(), Counter()
for row in color_scores.itertuples():
    for i in row[1].split(', '):
        c1[i] += row[2]
        c2[i] += 1

s = pd.Series(c1).div(pd.Series(c2))
print (s)
blue       9.866667
green     13.600000
orange     6.200000
pink       8.266667
purple     6.200000
red       12.400000
yellow    11.100000
dtype: float64

color_avgs['new'] = color_avgs['colors'].map(s)
print (color_avgs)
   colors        new
0    blue   9.866667
1     red  12.400000
2   green  13.600000
3  purple   6.200000
4  orange   6.200000
5    pink   8.266667
6  yellow  11.100000
```

**Explanation**:

1. Loop by [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and for each row add to 2 Counters splitted values of `colors` and count
2. Create Series and divide for `mean`
3. Last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) new column

Pandas only solution:

```
s = (color_scores.set_index('score')['colors']
                 .str.split(', ', expand=True)
                 .stack()
                 .reset_index(name='a')
                 .groupby('a')['score'].mean())

color_avgs['new'] = color_avgs['colors'].map(s)
print (color_avgs)
   colors        new
0    blue   9.866667
1     red  12.400000
2   green  13.600000
3  purple   6.200000
4  orange   6.200000
5    pink   8.266667
6  yellow  11.100000
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to `DataFrame`
2. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
3. Aggregate mean per groups
4. Last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) new column

Comment: Sorry for the unnoticed mark dup, just getting problem with downvoter at the same time I left the note to you .. sign.

Comment: @Wen - It is no problem :)

Comment: Will take your suggestion, adding more explanation :-)